# Perl - Which module is the best to do SSH, SFTP with public key authentication on windows

Tags: perl, ssh, public-key-encryption

Come back here with another perl + SSH problem.

Here is my situation:

I need to connect from a server A to a server B with SSH. Within this SSH connection, I need to make some SFTP connections beside other commands.
Concerning the authentication, I need to use the public key authentication.
All of that in a Perl script and both server A and B are windows.

Do you know any perl module matching these constraints?

I tried:

1. Net::SSH::Any, but the API does not mention the public key authentication
2. Net::OpenSSH, the API says it's not working on windows
3. Net::SSH::Perl, the API mentions the usage of the private key. When I tried passing it, it fails (code below). If I tried with Putty, it works.

Extra question: I read that storing the private key (on server A in my case) is not safe at all (and I understand why), is there a way to avoid that?

Code:

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("server-ip", identity_files => [ 'path-to-private-key' ], option => ["BatchMode yes"]);
$ssh->login('login');
```

Answer (score 6):

I am the author of Net::OpenSSH and Net::SSH::Any.

Net::SSH::Any does support public key authentication but there are a couple of hidden requirements:

- The key must be in OpenSSH format (you can use PuTTY companion utilities to convert keys between formats, google for it)
- A file with the public key is also required and it must be placed at `"${path_to_private_key}.pub"`.

Besides that, over the last couple of months I have been working on improving Net::SSH::Any and on the way fixing lots of important bugs on the underlying Net::SSH2 module and the libssh2 library. If you feel courageous, you may like to try the development version (you will need the git versions of the three packages, Net::SSH::Any, Net::SSH2 and libssh2).

I would really appreciate getting any feedback about it, specially when running under Windows.

Comment: `A file with the public key is also required..` that is interesting as I think there was no public key when I tested `Net::SSH::Any` on strawberry

Comment: @mpapec: I have added a test for that case, now, at least, you get an informative error message.

Comment: @salva: thanks for the feedback. I read the Any.pm on github. Do I need to write: "$ssh = Net::SSH::Any->new($server, user => $login, key_path => "PATH_TO_KEY.pub"); ?

Comment: @el_grom: no, the argument to `key_path` is the name of the file containing the private key. Then, the module infers the name of the file containing the public key appending `.pub` to it.

Comment: @salva, sorry for the delay. I tried this "Net::SSH::Any->new($server, user => $login, key_path => "C:\\temp\\key")". In the temp folder, I put both private and public keys (respectively named "key" and "key.pub"). When I try this, I got an authentication failed on this line. I tried with Putty and it works.
--> What did I do wrong?
--> Why is the public key mandatory?
In my situation, the public key is stored in the remote server (in WinSSHD)

Comment: Putty uses its own custom key format that is not supported by `libssh2`. You have to convert the key to OpenSSH format.